# Tcl - match closing bracket in glob pattern

Tags: tcl, glob

How would I get the `switch` statement to math the closing bracket? I tried both `"[][]"` and `"[[\]]"`

```
set x "]"

switch -glob $x {
    "[[\]]" {
        puts "MATCH ]"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to match `]` as part of a group of characters in `switch`, you've only got a few options:

1. Use `-regexp` matching instead of `-glob`. It's more complex, requires a different pattern, but it's also definitely more flexible (especially when it comes to things like this).

   ```
   switch -regexp $x {
       ^[][(){}]$ {
           puts "Matched!"
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use multiple clauses with body sharing:

   ```
   switch -glob $x {
       {\[} - {\]} - [(){}] {
           puts "Matched!"
       }
   }
   ```

What you *can't* do is put a `]` in a glob match set except as a non-initial part of a range (the glob matcher is pretty dumb, but fast). There isn't any suitable range that would match exactly what you're after here, so a single glob won't work.

Comment: This is all based on your comment on Noxx's _otherwise great_ answer that you're after matching this (if it worked): `[()[]{}]`

Answer (score 5):

you can use:

```
set x "]";
switch -glob $x {
    \] {
        puts "MATCH ]"
    }
}
```

or to match more than the bracket:

```
set x "foo]bar";
switch -glob $x {
    *\]* {
        puts "MATCH ]"
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, a literal `]` works (this in something parsed as a _list_) and so does `{]}`. Globbing only treats `]` as special when it follows an (unescaped) `[`.

Comment: I need it as one of a few options. My full program has something like this `"[()[]{}]"`, except of course that doesn't work. But your example will only match the bracket, nothing else.

Comment: @DonalFellows And it is apparent from the question. In the question I am trying to match both an opening and closing bracket.